# Return all columns with distinct on multiple columns in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct

I have 5 columns in sql table and I need all the 5 columns as out put but with distinct operation on three columns

Need to return all the columns with distinct operation on three column

How to achive this?

```
Timestamp                   Name    State     Context
2013-06-24 11:51:03.2550000 tst1    Started     E1
2013-06-24 11:56:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
2013-06-24 11:51:03.2550000 tst1    Started     E1
2013-06-24 11:56:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
2013-06-24 11:45:03.2550000 tst1    Started     E1
2013-06-24 11:50:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
2013-06-24 11:45:03.2550000 tst1    Started     E1
2013-06-24 11:50:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
```

Here I am getting all the distinct result for above table by applying distinct on three columns using below query. But I need the distinct of these three columns also need to select context column without applying distict on Context column

> SELECT DISTINCT Timestamp,Name,State   FROM TableName group by 
>   Timestamp,Name,State

Rephrasing my question :

I need to select unique columns from above table . Here only unquie column selection considered as Timestamp,Name,State

```
Timestamp                   Name    State     Context
2013-06-24 11:51:03.2550000 tst1    Started     E1
2013-06-24 11:56:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
2013-06-24 11:45:03.2550000 tst1    Started E1
2013-06-24 11:50:03.2550000 tst1    Completed   E1
```

Comment: What about the other two columns? What kind of aggregation/modification you wanna do with them? Please add an example of the result you're trying to achieve

Comment: Updated the question with example

Comment: can you show the output you want ?

Comment: But then what you expect to return for Context?  E1 or E2?

Comment: Rephrased my question

Comment: There are two unique Started in that data.  A sample a single value for Context does not address the question.

Comment: Blam : Updated the sample result data...Also not sure why people down voting this question.

Comment: Because in 6 edits you still don't have a clear question.  You state 5 columns and the sample is 4 columns.   In the sample there is only one value for the 4th so not clear how to handle that.  For that sample you could just select distinct on all 4 columns.  Did you try my answer?

Comment: If it worked then consider checking it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can group by 3 but must use some type of aggregate function like min or max on the other two

```
select col1, col2, col3, max(col4), min(col5) 
from tbl 
group by col1, col2, col3
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a groupby for the three columns you want 'distinct'.

Comment: Wrong, you must have some sort of aggregate for the other columns!