# Translating Linq Code Block into SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

The main goal is to migrate the appropriate data from one table to another, and since my skills are not sharp in sql, I wrote the logic using linq and foreach statement to accomplish what is needed. However, a sql script is needed to run in different environment, so I started to translate what I previously wrote into sql, and boom my sql thought process was left broken at the GroupBy and looping shores.

**Here is my attempt which in fact returns an accurate data result**:

```
SELECT BookID FROM (SELECT bt.BookID, pt.PaperID, ppt.PropID
FROM BooksTable AS bt
JOIN PapersTable AS pt
ON bt.BookID = pt.BookID
JOIN PapersPropertiesTable AS ppt
ON pt.PaperID = ppt.PaperID) AS ResultSet
GROUP BY BookID
```

**Here is the code where I hit a rock**:

```
foreach (var i in ResultSetGroupedByBookID)
{
    var resultToMigrate= i.DistinctBy(j => j.PropID).ToList();

    foreach (var j in resultToMigrate)
    {
        db.InsertPropsProcedure(j.BookID, j.PropID);
    }
}
```

**The major challenges**:

- GroupingBy that returns an inner result set with other columns included
- Loop through the inner result set, DistinctBy PropID and return another set
- Loop through the new set, call the insert procedure and pass the params

**Update**:

I selected Stepen's answer for its simplicty; however, I ran into the scenario where I needed to Distinct By multiple columns while returning a third, so I had to do the following [modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320732/2093880):

```
INSERT INTO Table2(BookID, PropID, PropValue)
SELECT DISTINCT bt.BookID, ppt.PropID, MAX(ppt.PropValue) AS PropValue
FROM BooksTable AS bt
JOIN PapersTable AS pt ON bt.BookID = pt.BookID
JOIN PapersPropertiesTable AS ppt ON pt.PaperID = ppt.PaperID
GROUP BY bt.BookID, ppt.PropertyID
ORDER BY bt.BookID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what are you trying to do exactly, but your sql query can be written as following:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT bt.BookID
  FROM BooksTable AS bt
  JOIN PapersTable AS pt ON bt.BookID = pt.BookID
  JOIN PapersPropertiesTable AS ppt ON pt.PaperID = ppt.PaperID;
```

- No need for the inner query.
- No need for group by.
- Just use `DISTINCT`.

You mihgt need to use `INSERT INTO SELECT` to insert the result of this query into another table:

```
  INSERT INTO Table2(BookID,PropID)
  SELECT DISTINCT bt.BookID, ppt.PropID
  FROM BooksTable AS bt
  JOIN PapersTable AS pt ON bt.BookID = pt.BookID
  JOIN PapersPropertiesTable AS ppt ON pt.PaperID = ppt.PaperID
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know the SQL & want to translate it into LINQ
or if you know LINQ & want to translate it to SQL

Best tool is [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question and code and inferring a little bit from the code, my understanding is that you want to retrieve a list of BookIds with associated Paper Properties and then for each one execute a stored procedure.  One way to accomplish this with a SQL-only approach rather than having C# orchestrate the calls would be to use a cursor in place of the result of the LINQ query.  Here's an example:

```
DECLARE migrate_cursor CURSOR
FOR
SELECT DISTINCT bt.BookID, ppt.PropID
FROM BooksTable AS bt
  INNER JOIN PapersTable AS pt
    ON bt.BookID = pt.BookID
  INNER JOIN PapersPropertiesTable AS ppt
    ON pt.PaperID = ppt.PaperID;

OPEN migrate_cursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM migrate_cursor  
INTO @bookId, @propId;  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   EXECUTE my_insert_props_procedure @bookId, @propId

   FETCH NEXT FROM migrate_cursor  
   INTO @bookId, @propId;  
END;

CLOSE migrate_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE migrate_cursor;
```

Now if this was a large resultset, you would want to take into consideration things like making the cursor forward-only and read-only and avoiding locks, but this gets the general idea across without overly complicating the example.  You can get more detailed information from the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/cursors-transact-sql