# Fault Tolerant jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate when duplicate key

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have one SQL that fetch big number of rows and then insert to database all in one iteration.

> INSERT INTO Summary
> (Name,StartDate,EndDate,InitialSize,Completed,Remaining)
> SELECT
> (Status.Type + ' ' +Status.Generic) AS
> Name,DATEADD(day, -28,  Status.Pat2) AS StartDate,
> DATEADD(day, 1, Status.Pat2) AS EndDate, COUNT(*) AS
> InitialSize, SUM(CASE WHEN Status.sw = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0
> END) AS Completed, SUM(CASE WHEN Status.sw = 'Y' THEN 0
> ELSE 1 END) AS Remainig FROM .......

```
jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql);
```

How can I make this to be faultTolerant meaning if there is exception due to duplicate key (column Name) then insert will continue without the duplicate row.

Thanks you

Comment: which RDBMS.....?

Comment: I am using  SQL Server

Comment: There are  elegant solutions (or workaround if you want) in several RDBMS.
In MySQL you would use [INSERT IGNORE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/), in Oracle  [`insert /*+ ignore_row_on_dupkey_index (...`](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-skip-duplicate-key-errors-ora-00001-in-oracle-database)
but in SQL Server you would  have to use either subquery to eliminate the existing keys or switch to the  `MERGE` statement - see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10703752/4808122)